# Clicking on the image will crash the Android app

Tags: java, android

I am making a E-Commerce in ANDROID STUDIO 3.5.3 using Java. What should be here is to show the details when click on the image. But when I click on the image the main function comes up. I can't find any error.

Code for ProductDetailsActivity as follows:

```
public class ProductDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView productImage;
    private ElegantNumberButton numberButton;
    private TextView productPrice, productDescription, productName;
    private String productID = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_details);

        productID = getIntent().getStringExtra("pid");

        numberButton = (ElegantNumberButton) findViewById(R.id.number_btn);
        productImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.product_image_details);
        productName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_name_details);
        productDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_description_details);
        productPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_price_details);

        getProductDetails(productID);
    }

    private void getProductDetails(String productID)
    {
        DatabaseReference productsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

        productsRef.child(productID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                if (snapshot.exists())
                {
                    Products products = snapshot.getValue(Products.class);

                    productName.setText(products.getPname());
                    productPrice.setText(products.getPrice());
                    productDescription.setText(products.getDescription());
                    Picasso.get().load(products.getImage()).into(productImage);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

HomeActivity code for going to the ProductsDetailsActivity as follows:

```
productViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProductDetailsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("pid", products.getPid());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
```

XML code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProductDetailsActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_image_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_image_details"
        android:text="Product Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_description_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_name_details"
        android:text="Product Description"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_price_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_description_details"
        android:text="Product Price"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
        android:id="@+id/number_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:textSize="16dp"
        app:initialNumber="1"
        app:finalNumber="10"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_price_details"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >
    </com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat Snippet is:

```
2020-11-15 09:14:49.960 32412-32412/? I/ample.ecommerc: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-11-15 09:14:50.316 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce I/ample.ecommerc: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2020-11-15 09:14:50.349 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2020-11-15 09:14:50.410 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2020-11-15 09:14:50.422 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2020-11-15 09:14:50.440 32412-32441/com.example.ecommerce I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:17 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0
2020-11-15 09:14:50.440 32412-32441/com.example.ecommerce I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite
2020-11-15 09:14:50.457 32412-32441/com.example.ecommerce W/ample.ecommerc: Unsupported class loader
2020-11-15 09:14:50.459 32412-32441/com.example.ecommerce W/ample.ecommerc: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2020-11-15 09:14:50.494 32412-32441/com.example.ecommerce V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-11-15 09:14:50.566 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce W/ample.ecommerc: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate()Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, linking)
2020-11-15 09:14:50.573 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
2020-11-15 09:14:50.580 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce W/ample.ecommerc: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-11-15 09:14:50.583 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce W/ample.ecommerc: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-11-15 09:14:50.583 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.example.ecommerce, 1:65208155721:android:c12bc5c52bc2a76ae54998
2020-11-15 09:14:50.585 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 31049
2020-11-15 09:14:50.585 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-11-15 09:14:50.586 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.ecommerce
2020-11-15 09:14:50.586 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2020-11-15 09:14:50.694 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce W/ample.ecommerc: Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic; (light greylist, linking)
2020-11-15 09:14:50.724 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-11-15 09:14:50.750 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce W/ample.ecommerc: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-11-15 09:14:50.750 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce W/ample.ecommerc: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-11-15 09:14:50.750 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce W/ample.ecommerc: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-11-15 09:14:50.750 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce W/ample.ecommerc: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-11-15 09:14:50.750 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce W/ample.ecommerc: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-11-15 09:14:50.750 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce W/ample.ecommerc: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; (light greylist, reflection)
2020-11-15 09:14:50.782 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-11-15 09:14:50.822 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-11-15 09:14:50.835 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 440758511
2020-11-15 09:14:50.879 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2020-11-15 09:14:50.966 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-11-15 09:14:50.971 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-11-15 09:14:51.006 32412-32449/com.example.ecommerce I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 50f1b2d, I1b05bd271c
    Build Date                       : 04/09/19
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.03
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
2020-11-15 09:14:51.006 32412-32449/com.example.ecommerce I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch32
2020-11-15 09:14:51.020 32412-32449/com.example.ecommerce I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
2020-11-15 09:14:51.030 32412-32449/com.example.ecommerce I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-11-15 09:14:51.032 32412-32449/com.example.ecommerce I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-11-15 09:14:51.032 32412-32449/com.example.ecommerce I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-11-15 09:14:51.033 32412-32449/com.example.ecommerce D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2020-11-15 09:14:51.056 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce W/AutofillManager: setSaveUiState(2070846167, true) called on existing session 1784228482; cancelling it
2020-11-15 09:14:51.120 32412-32412/com.example.ecommerce I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3652 bytes, containing 1 windows, 11 views
2020-11-15 09:14:51.123 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-11-15 09:14:51.126 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 5
2020-11-15 09:14:56.274 32412-32445/com.example.ecommerce V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
    ����,������ .
2020-11-15 09:14:58.360 32412-32439/com.example.ecommerce I/ample.ecommerc: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=0 is saved saved_to_disk=0 resolve_classes_delay=8000
    ����,������ .
```

Comment: Try replacing your productID initialization with this ```getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("pid");```

Answer (score 0):

Some photo's use a different format of color to display photos and Android can not handle that Version of color. This guy made a video on it [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXKvwPjCGnY)